# Convert a JPG (png / GIf, etc) as a 64base String:

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 7 and Indy 9 on XP SP3.

I have HTML with multiple `<img>` tags in it.

I want to convert `<img src="filepath" ...>` tags into `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,...">` tags.

As an exercise, I planned to do it on each image like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR
   Str    : AnsiString;
   Stream1, Stream2  : TFileStream;
   Decoder : TIDEncoderMime;

BEGIN
   Stream1 := TFilestream.Create(Curdir + '\solopgang.jpg', fmOpenRead);
   Stream2 := TFilestream.Create('C:\test221.html', fmCreate);
   Try
      Decoder := TIDEncoderMime.Create(NIl);
      Str := decoder.Encode(Stream1^, length(Stream1));
      StrToFile('c:\test221.html',Str);
   Finally
      FreeAndNil(Decoder);
      Stream1.Free;
      Stream2.Free;
  END;
end;
```

But, when I show it in my `TWebBrowser`, I get only the outer frame of the Image, and I don't know why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi 7 BASE64 function to make a showable <img src="data: image/jpg; data, xxxx -/> string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587218/delphi-7-base64-function-to-make-a-showable-img-src-data-image-jpg-data-xxx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909096/convert-base64-to-bitmap    ||     

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587218/delphi-7-base64-function-to-make-a-showable-img-src-data-image-jpg-data-xxx      ||    

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795263/binary-to-base64-delphi

Comment: This code is somewhat messy. You create `Stream2` but never use it. You create `Decoder` inside the `try` which is a very mistake. You call an encoder `Decoder` which is pretty confusing. You use `Stream1^` which makes no sense and I don't see why it would even compile. Similarly with `length(Stream1)`. How can that compile? So on the face of it, this code looks fake. You claim to have successfully run this code but that cannot be the case. Finally, there are a bazillion questions here about how to perform base64 encoding. Do we really need one more?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It is something I have picked up from different places in the web. But I'll clean it up and ask again.

Comment: Oh and one more comment is that the use of `AnsiString` feels wrong. That's going to give you headaches at some point down the line.

Answer (score 4):

As David mentioned in comments, your code does not compile as shown.  It should be more like this instead:

```
uses
  ..., Classes, IdCoderMIME;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream : TFileStream;
  Encoder : TIdEncoderMIME;
begin
  Stream := TFileStream.Create(Curdir + '\solopgang.jpg', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    Encoder := TIdEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
    try
      StrToFile('c:\test221.html', Encoder.Encode(Stream));
    finally
      Encoder.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you upgrade to Indy 10, you can use this instead:

```
uses
  ..., Classes, IdGlobal, IdCoderMIME;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream1, Stream2 : TStream;
begin
  Stream1 := TIdReadFileExclusiveStream.Create(Curdir + '\solopgang.jpg');
  try
    Stream2 := TIdFileCreateStream.Create('c:\test221.html');
    try
      TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeStream(Stream1, Stream2);
    finally
      Stream2.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It works like i have hoped . But it appears that JPG NOT EQUAL JPEG;  and JPEG (camera's) NOT EQUAL JPG (computer).  In some of the JPG's (not JPEG)'s I get a variable height of black-pixels and then the rest of the image.    If I create an JPG and JPEG image myself (eg. PAINT, photoshop etc.) on the machine the image is shown correct from line 1 to last line. Only very few CAMERA-images are shown correct.  Do you know why ?

Comment: @KristianSander JPG and JPEG are the same thing. JPG contains metadata, a PC generated JPG may have different metadata than a camera generated JPG. For instance, camera JPGs may have metadata for describing the camera's orientation. That can affect how the JPG is displayed in orientation aware viewers. You might have to strip out the metadata. There are plenty of libraries available for manipulating JPGs.

Comment: Thanks for updating me.

Comment: Would be nice if you would include the USES units when adding code samples.

Comment: @Toby I have updated my examples to include `uses` clauses

Comment: @RemyLebeau Much easier to find - TY!
BTW "Str" not defined in Indy 10 version.

Comment: @Toby I have fixed it